# How to use jQuery to select this element: <span style="vertical-align:bottom">

Tags: jquery, css

How can I use jQuery (or vanilla JS, or CSS) to select the following span?

```
<span style="vertical-align:bottom">
```

The twist is that I cannot put a class on the span or otherwise modify the HTML, as this span is outputted by a wonky CMS.

Another twist is that it is not the first span in the td, so it would be tricky to target with CSS by like td>span or something.  I suppose I could follow the path and select it with CSS by some long string of selectors but it's a span inside a td, but that td is like the third td in the second tr in the table.  Is that a better way to select it?  All I need to do is remove that style or make it vertical-align:top.

So can I use jQuery to select an element based on what's in the style attribute?  I'll worry about if it's the only element with that style on the page later, this is the part that has me stuck.

Can I do this?

```
span[style*="bottom"]
```

Comment: `$("span[style^=vertical-align]")`

Comment: Just a small note: attribute^=property is a CSS 3 selector

Answer (score 3):

```
var $targets = $("span[style^='verticial-align:']"); //returns all spans with vertical align set
```

Answer (score 3):

**Jquery:**

You can use `$("span[style^=vertical-align]")` as mentioned.

If you want to target only the first one or the second etc you can 
add:

```
/*first span element that has this attribute and property*/
$("span[style^=vertical-align]").eq(0);
```

**CSS 3**

Same idea:

```
span[style^=vertical-align] {
     some properties
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

```
$('span[style*="vertical-align:bottom"]');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x8yJ6/).

The `[style*="vertical-align:bottom"]` looks to see whether the `style` attribute of the element *contains* (not starts-with) the string `vertical-align:bottom` (which is slightly more reliable than simply using the `starts-with* (`style^="vertical-align:bottom"]`) selector.

Though this is dependant on knowing whether or not there's white-space present (note that, in the demo (above), it fails to select the first element). Or you could use the following:

```
$('span[style]').filter(function(){
    return this.style.verticalAlign === 'bottom';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x8yJ6/1/).

The above demos use the following HTML:

```
<span style="vertical-align: bottom">This has <code>style="vertical-align: bottom"</code></span>
<span style="vertical-align:bottom">This has <code>style="vertical-align:bottom"</code></span>
<span>This span has no style attribute at all</span>
<span style="color:#f00;vertical-align:bottom">This has <code>style="color:#f00;vertical-align: bottom"</code></span>
```

References:

- [Attribute-contains (`[attribute*="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).